# Derive a second order difference approximation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation

Derive a second order difference approximation to $y(a)$ using the values $$y(a + h/2), \space y(a + h) \space,\space y(a + 2h)$$ Verify the order of your approximation.

Have no idea how to tackle this one. Any help or hints are appreciated.

Comment: @par I have tried using the ansatz method but I don't know if that is even correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you learned about the method of undetermined coefficients? It's
a good place to start:

Roughly speaking, this method looks for constants $\alpha$, $\beta$,
and $\gamma$, such that
$$
y^{\prime\prime}(a)\approx\alpha y(a+h/2)+\beta y(a+h)+\gamma y(a+2h)
$$
Begin by assuming $y$ is smooth (i.e. it has derivatives of all orders)
and plug in the power series around $a$ for $y(a+h/2)$, $y(a+h)$,
and $y(a+2h)$. Pick $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ such that
the zero-th and first equal to $y^{\prime\prime}(a)$ plus higher
order derivatives.

For a more **complete introduction**, see Section 1.2 of http://www.siam.org/books/ot98/sample/OT98Chapter1.pdf.

Comment: thanks for the answer. No I haven't. Do you have anything I can read, or should I just Google?

Comment: I have added a PDF link.

Comment: wow thanks for the link :)

Comment: They are setting the coefficients of $u(\overline{x})$ and $u^{\prime\prime}(\overline{x})$ to zero by taking $a+b+c=0$ and $b+4c=0$, respectively. To keep the $u^\prime(\overline{x})$ term, they set $(b+2c)h=1$. (not a typo)